# Handling Date picker using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have two date pickers in my web page which is Start Date and End Date. I need to click on both dates but when I search for element there are same elements called. but there is one unique element name.How can I call those elements.

Date Picker 1 HTML code:-

```
<span>Start Date:</span>
<input id="courseStartDate" class="date-range required hasDatepicker" type="text" size="20" value="" onchange="startDateChanged()" name="courseStartDate">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../../images/Calender.png" alt="..." title="...">
```

Date Picker 2 HTML code:-

```
<span>End Date:</span>
<input id="courseEndDate" class="date-range required hasDatepicker" type="text" size="20" value="" onchange="endDateChanged()" name="courseEndDate">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../../images/Calender.png" alt="..." title="...">
```

Comment: I have tried with the following but still not clicking the image of calendar     1. driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='...']")).click();
 2.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id= courseStartDate]"));
 3.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='courseStartDate']")).click();
 4.driver.findElement(By.name("courseStartDate")).click();
 5.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='courseStartDate']/img[alt='...']")).click();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can handle *date-picker* using a `List`:

1. Fetch all values from the *year*, *month* and *day* table using into a `List`
2. Loop and compare the `List`'s elements with the input: *year*, *month* and *day*

```java
List<WebElement> yearList = driver
   .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody"))
   .findElements(By.tagName("span"));

for (int i = 0; i < yearList.size(); i++) {
  if (yearList.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(date_dd_MM_yyyy[2])) {
    
    yearList.get(i).click();
    System.out.println("Year found successfully..");
    break;
  } else if (i == yearList.size()) {
    System.out.println("Year not found.");
  }
}
```

For a detailed tutorial see following blog-post:
[Selenium JAVA Automation Tips & Tricks](https://qaautomationdesk.blogspot.com/2018/04/step-by-step-appium-tutorial-for.html)

Comment: I formatted your answer. It's essentially just a copy from the blog-post you linked. Unfortunately this does not answer the question asked. Let me rephrase how I understood the question: _How to get the HTML-element of the given "date-picker"?_. Whereas your answered: _How to find a  given "date" (`date_dd_MM_yyyy[2]`) within a table._ Please focus on the question and consult [answer].

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `img` tag is not a child of the `input` tag, but the tag right after it - a sibling. Also, in your 5th attempt, you're trying to refer to the `alt` attribute of `img`, so you should write `@alt` instead of `alt`.

I would recommend using the `class` attribute instead of `alt`, like this:

1) start date

```
(.//*[@id='courseStartDate']/following-sibling::img[@class='ui-datepicker-trigger'])[1]
```

2) end date

```
(.//*[@id='courseEndDate']/following-sibling::img[@class='ui-datepicker-trigger'])[1]
```

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) for more information on following-siblings and xpath axes in general.

Comment: I tried with the given code and adding @to my 5th attempt but still not working. Can you provide any other solution on this

Comment: Please provide a bigger code sample for me to see where and how the given solution was used. Is your code encased in a try/catch block?